# Why am I not seeing objects that I'm adding to my storyboard in my ViewController.swift file?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and I'm having a hard time understanding the platform. I would like to know why whenever I'm adding objects (buttons, labels, image views, etc.) to my storyboard, I don't see any change in my .swift file connected to its view controller.

If someone could explain it to me precisely it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because there is no auto-sync. Please read [Connect the UI to Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1) in Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)

Answer (score 0):

Because there shouldn't be any in the first place. Connections between the Interface Builder (IB) and your code must be placed by hand (either by writing them first and connecting by ctrl-dragging to the function, or letting xCode generate them by ctrl-dragging them into place).

If you need to reference any views you have in interface builder from your code, make sure that:

1. IB knows the class the view belongs to (set this in the Identity Inspector to the right for the main container view, usually the UIViewController)
2. There is a corresponding `@IBOutlet` (or `@IBAction`) marked property (or function)

Then just ctrl-drag from the object in IB to the property in the code, and everything should run smoothly.

Here's some [info](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev31645f17f) if you need more help connecting the views in the IB to your code.

Happy coding!

Comment: So where exactly does the IB data is stored. Is it in a file or ? Thanks.

Comment: In the `.storyboard` file (or a `.xib` file if you use one). These files are internally Xml files that represent what you see in the IB. You aren't really supposed to care about them, because (ideally) you should only interact with them through the IB or your version control system.